# Add line breaks in mail function php

Tags: php

I'd like to send email using mail function.
Want to add line breaks as follows.

```
$msg = 'aaaaa'.'\r\n'.'bbbbbb'.'\r\n';
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"\r\n";
$to = 'test@test.com';
mail($to,'Subject',$msg,$headers);
```

But not working.

How can I send email as follows.

aaaaa

bbbbbb

Comment: Why would you want line breaks in your header?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single

Comment: I need to add something more to header like this. $headers .= 'From' .'\r\n'

Comment: @JonathanYanivBenAvraham: Headers are terminated by newline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add line break you need to add "\n", not '\n'

Answer (score 5):

New line is `"\n"`, not `'\n'` (double quotes instead of single-quotes).

```
$msg = 'aaaaa'."\n".'bbbbbb'."\n";
```

Explanation is here:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double

*If the string is enclosed in double-quotes ("), PHP will interpret more escape sequences for special characters*

Comment: Why single quotes will not work, while double quotes works? Any explanation?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php look on section **double quoted** - there is explanation: *If the string is enclosed in double-quotes ("), PHP will interpret more escape sequences for special characters*

Answer (score 2):

You may use html tags in your mail body like this(`<br />` breaks to new-line) :

```
$message = '<html><body>';
$message .= '<h1>Hello, World!</h1><p>Hello<br />This is in a newline</p>';
$message .= '</body></html>';
```

**If you want to send plain text then you may just use `\n`.**

In your case :

```
$msg = "aaaaa \r\n bbbbbb \r\n";
```

And your headers :

```
$headers = "From: Name <info@name.com> \r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0 \r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 \r\n";
```

> **Note**: In case of **single quoted string**,
>   To specify a literal backslash, double it (\). All other instances of
>   backslash will be treated as a literal backslash: this means that the
>   other escape sequences you might be used to, such as \r or \n, will be
>   output literally as specified rather than having any special meaning.